# VB.NET Selenium how to get specific value on span

Tags: vb.net, selenium

[image]

I'm new to this selenium on vb.net, and I'm currently stuck here.

My current code right now is this one and idk how can I get the value inside 'Full Name'.

```
TextBox1.Text = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[text()='Full Name']")).Text
```

By the way, the site is: fakeaddressgenerator.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TextBox1.Text = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[6]/div[2]/strong/input")).GetAttribute("value")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this definitely solves my problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not much into VB.NET but this is what I can suggest:-

```
TextBox1.Text = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr/td[contains(text(),'Full Name')]/following-sibling::td/")).Text
```

Please mark this as an answer if it helps in solving your issue.